# Objective-C How do I crop video to the size of the capture view?

Tags: objective-c, video, avfoundation, crop

So I am using AVFoundation to create a custom full screen camera. When I record a video on the full screen camera, it appears to be a zoomed out version of the video, so I want to get the video to be exactly how I saw it being recorded. So how can I crop the video to the dimensions of my capture view.

Answer (score 0):

Your recording of video is fine. What you are looking at while recording is your `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`. You need to play with the `videoGravity` of this previewLayer. 
Try using this:

```
    previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect;
```

It will fix all the aspect ratio issues.